# Merge CSV file to Vector Layer using common attributes in QGIS python scripting

Tags: qgis, python, mmqgis

I have a vector layer and a delimited text (csv) file -- they both have the common attribute `attribid` -- how can I add the columns of the csv file to the vector layer merging on the the `attribid` key using a python script?

I'm aware that I can use MMQGIS's combine feature to do this, but I could not get it to work using a python script.